Change of coordinates and compatibility condition for an area constraint
Let $x=x(a,b), y=y(a,b)$ and consider the change of coordinates generated by the infinitesimal transformation $\delta a = -b \delta \phi$ and $\delta b = a \delta \phi$ for some function $\delta\phi$. This is an (rigid or isometric) rotation of the coordinates. Initially, we take $\delta \phi$ to be independent of $(a,b)$.
Let $(x,y)$ satisfy $$\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(a,b)}=x_ay_b-x_by_a=J(a,b).$$ Are there any restrictions on the functions $(x,y)$ so that the function $J$ remains fixed under the coordinate transformation?

 I believe this implies that there is a compatibility condition restricting $x_{aa}+x_{bb}=y_{aa}+y_{bb}=0$.

What about the case where $\phi=\phi(b)$, that is the angle of the rotation depends on one of the independent variables? Is there a corresponding compatibility condition?

By fixed under the coordinate transformation do you mean that $J(a,b) = J(x(a,b), y(a,b))$?

@Al.G. I mean that if $a\to a +\delta a$ and $b\to b+\delta b$, then this transformed system $x\to \tilde{x}$ and $y\to \tilde{y}$ is such that $J(x,y) =J(\tilde{x},\tilde{y})$.
